# Validate form using Angularjs with ajax request

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I have html code

```
<input type="text" name="username">
    <label for="">
        Email
    </label>
<input type="email" name="email">
```

I want use ajax check in database if have username and email ,then show message error else show success .
I'm doing the same with https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way but not work with angular 1.6.x

In register.php I dont know how to code . Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JavaScript [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a good place to start. Once you are familiar with the basics have a look on how [Angular works](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started). If you are just looking to finish off your task read about Angular [validations](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html) here.